# While pushing code to gitlab username password dialog box open, What should i put in username and password

Tags: git, gitlab

I already done username and email config.

```
git -config username git --config email address
```

If i enter my username and account password it is showing me authentication error.

Comment: Provide more details. What error exactly do you see? Do you use your GitLab credentials?

Comment: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied, If i enter my username and account password

Comment: So what should be the username and password

Comment: Are you able to log in correctly at GitLab website using the same username and password? Do you use Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm using windows, and I'm able to access gitlab website with username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be due wrong credentials stored in Windows Credential Manager.

1. Start -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials
2. Search gitlab.com entry
3. Remove entry (editing did not work in my case)
4. Add it again with correct username and password

Comment: If you are not comfortable with putting password again and again then consider using ssh for cloning your project.

Comment: @bughunter I'm facing this issue again

Answer (score 0):

You can only push to the repositories that you have access to.